# form submit checkbox value

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have a bike
  I have a car

---

I know when the form is submitted the value will be vehicle=Bike&vehicle=Car if both are ticked

Is there a way to make the value to be vehicle=Bike,Car

Put them into one variable then separated in a comma

Comment: Are you using `method="GET"` to submit your form?

Comment: You should give different names to these checkboxes and join values in the receiving script.

Comment: I want to use the method=POST"

Comment: Once submit ed format any way you like

Comment: I mean is there anyway the submitted will be in a "vehicle=Bike,Car" value already? or can i only format it already receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using POST and multiple check boxes, set the name of each check box like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Bike">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Car">
```

Then when your form is submitted you will receive an array of all the checked boxes and their values in the array:

```
$_POST['vehicle'][];
```

Now if both boxes are checked you can retrieve the values in a foreach loop:

```
foreach($_POST['vehicle'] as $type){
   echo "Type = ".$type;
}
```

With this you will get an output of

```
Type = Bike
Type = Car
```

Comment: Found a way to make i what i want through this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
<input type="hidden" name="vechiclesStr" id="vechiclesStr">


//on submitting,
document.getElementById("vechiclesStr").value = document.formname.vechicle.join();
```